# Как мне улучшать свою программу без потери того что я уже сделал

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

У меня есть программа, она работает, но теперь я хочу её улучшить. Но возможно такое что при попытке её улучшить, она перестанет работать, и я не смогу вернуться к тому что было в начале. Чтобы сохранить рабочую версию мне каждый раз нужно делать копию проекта или есть что-нибудь попроще?

Comment: Отличное - враг хорошему!:)

Comment: Ваш вопрос напоминает старуху из сказки А.С. Пушкина  о золотой рыбке.:) Только вы - более расчетливая старуха.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ну а что такого. Вот я как-то раз переводил проект на `php` с "лапши" на `MVC`+ `OOP`. И точно не хотелось бы посередине процесса встрять. Так что зависит от того, что собирается и как улучшать. Но это уже автора проблема))

Comment: git может работать локально без залива в гитхабы)

Comment: Система контроля версий + тесты + книжка про рефакторинг вам в помощь

Comment: Если хочется изучать особенности системы контроля версий, читать тонну статей, перекраивать привычное восприятие и помнить море нюансов дабы не выстрелить себе в ногу, а также если вы безудержный любитель консоли, то это git.
Если же нужна готовая система версий, которая настолько же мощная как и git, но при этом стройна, логична и защищает от ошибок, да еще без консоли можно обойтись, то это mercurial
svn сразу мимо - оно уже не конкурент.

Comment: @vitidev: ваше мнение очень субъективно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin все мнения субъективны на этом сайте. Зато мое мнение сделано на основе **использования обеих** систем, а не по причине "мы выбрали гит потому что он более популярен/сдандарт/святой линус/только консоль-только хардкор"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Использовать **TFS** или **Git**. Применять для улучшений ветвление исходного кода
2. Можно так же использовать и ваш метод с копированием, но это анахронизм.

Answer (score 19):

Вы можете сделать одну из простых вещей это организовать репозиторий у себя на локальном диске.

Например под Windows удобная вещь как TortoiseSVN

С помощью него в процессе написания кода вы можете постоянно сохранять промежуточные результаты. И в случае неудачи всегда можно откатиться на любую сохраненную версию.

Также может использовать любой другой репозиторий. Популярны сейчас GIT и Mercurial.

Answer (score 12):

Данная задача давным-давно решена и её решение носит название "система контроля версий" (или "система управления версиями"). Она позволяет сохранять снимки дерева исходников проекта. В нужный момент программист указывает системе сделать снимок исходников (так называемый "коммит") и система сохраняет каким-либо образом в своём специальном каталоге данные, благодаря которым программист в любой момент времени сможет вернуться к этому коммиту. Можно возвращаться к любому коммиту, создавать новые ответвления, сливать ветки и т.п. Более подробную информацию можно получить из документации к конкретной системе. Примеры систем контроля версий: Git,
SVN, Mercurial, Bazaar и т.д.

P.S. Конечно, дело вкуса, но я бы порекомендовал Git.

Answer (score 8):

Много было сказано про систему контроля версий, но мало про:

- *юнит тесты*
- *рефакторинг*

На всякий случай, скажу мое скромное понимание:

*Юнит тесты* содержат код для проверки коректоности работы Ваших функций. После внесения изменений (*рефакторинга*) тесты менять не надо, они так же должны проходить (получать зачет).

*Рефакторинг* - изменение кода малыми порциями, маленькими шажками, пока код не станет чистым, понятным. Между этими шажками хорошо запускать *юнит-тесты*, чтоб проверить, что при изменениях не было внесено ошибок.

*Юнит тесты* в идеале должны быть подробными. *Юнит тест* одного метода должен покрывать все возможные варианты (ветки) прохождения по этому методу в зависимости от входных данных.

Про это много написано в интернете. Хотя, во многих случаях (особенно, если иметь ввиду малые пректы), игра не стоит свеч, то есть, не стоит того, чтобы замарачиваться с *тестами* и изучением подходов к *рефакторингу*.

---

По просьбе, привожу простой [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910138/unit-test-examples) *юнит теста*.

Есть класс, который проверяет корректность формата телефонного номера

```
public class PhoneValidator
{
    public bool IsValid(string phone)
    {
        return UseSomeRegExToTestPhone(phone);
    }
}
```

Для этого класса надо сделать такой *юнит тест*, чтобы проверить все возможные категории входных строк. Как верные так и неверные. Но в примере напишу только две входные строки, т.к. все варианты - много...

```
public void TestPhoneValidator()
{
    string goodPhone = "+7 (910) 555 12 12";
    string badPhone = "555 12"

    PhoneValidator validator = new PhoneValidator();

    Assert.IsTrue(validator.IsValid(goodPhone));
    Assert.IsFalse(validator.IsValid(badPhone));
    //и т.д.
}
```

*Assert* - сама проверка. Значение слова *Assert* - утверждать. Если утверждение не верно, то кидается Exception и тест не проходит. Класс `Assert` - часть [фреймворка тестирования](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/create-and-run-unit-tests-vs).

P.S. Для *C#* и *Visual Studio* можно закачать здоровскую нугетовскую ([Nuget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet)) библиотеку [FluentAssertions](http://www.fluentassertions.com/), чтобы было удобно делать асёрты.

Comment: Хотелось бы больше узнать про юнит тесты. Какие-нибудь простые примеры можно?

Comment: @Mikhail Danshin, простой один пример привел

Comment: @Mikhail Danshin, или Вы имели ввиду что-то более сложное?

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить использование бесплатной программы **sourceTree** (git). Она имеет удобный интерфейс на русском языке. По истечении месяца предлагается бесплатная регистрация. Можно хранить данные локально либо на удаленном репозитории (например github).
При создании нового хранилища указывается корневая папка проекта (как вариант), это значит что все что вложено в нее будет автоматически фиксироваться программой. Когда вы делаете изменения в файле (например улучшили ваш код), программа автоматически показывает изменения и предлагает их зафиксировать и прокомментировать, естественно к каждому изменению можно будет вернуться в любой момент времени.
для поиска просто вбейте в гугл **atlassian sourcetree**.