# Существует ли сайт для совместного программирования?

Tags: инструменты-разработчика

Существует ли сайт, на котором можно программировать, к примеру, с другом, и чтобы все изменения отображались в режиме реального времени? Желательно, чтобы весь код хранился на сайте.

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону различных сервисов совместной работы. Но, в IT обычно используют сервисы типа GitHub или ему подобные. Единственное, изменения в коде там отображаются не в реальном времени, а после commit'а. Однако это, ИМХО, и к лучшему. Так как стимулирует выкладывать в общий репозиторий только более-менее оформленное решение, даже если оно пока лишь только на правах черновика.

Comment: TeamViewer may be?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468803/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB/468806    для вас

Comment: А зачем прям в реальном времени? По-моему смотреть, как кто-то сидит и тупит^W думает и пробует написать по-разному, надолго зависая и возможно переписывая по нескольку раз (если заранее не спроектировано) будет не очень интересно

Comment: @andreymal смотреть бесконечно можно на три вещи: как горит огонь, как течет вода и как кто-то тупит в режиме реального времени. Это бесценно) Наблюдать, как кто-то идиотничает больше, чем ты сам)))

Comment: Просто хочется работать над проектом с другом. Чтобы он видел, что в данный момент печатаю я, а я чтобы видел, что печатает он.

Comment: @JarOK как правило, разработка ведется немного обособленно, т.е. один разрабатывает одну часть, например модуль "новости", другой - модуль "чат", и, в принципе, не должны пересекаться. И смысл как раз в том, чтоб быстрее разработка происходила - разделять. А когда оба роются в одном файле - смысла нет никакого. Такие вещи обычно творит IDE (netbeans, phpstorm), - они отображают сообщение, если кто-то начинает редактировать файл, в котором сейчас находитесь вы. Но такие сообщения замучают вас... и как бы то ни было лучше использовать системы контроля версий и разделить обязанности.

Comment: Да и сами подумайте, вот вы редактируете файл с формой отправки на сервер, час что-то делаете, все в реальном времени изменяется и тут заходит ваш друг и пытается там что-то изменить, у вас всё стирается, удаляет контролы или еще что-то. Вам это понравится?)) Это просто непродуктивно. Ведь ни одно приложение не сможет угадать, что нужно в данный момент изменять в файле, а что нет. Поэтому такое отображение изменений в реальном времени вообще не имеет смысла. Разве что для подкола над своими друзьями программистами на 1 апреля))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский одновременное отображение изменений в реальном времени - это основная фишка google docs. Не сказал бы, что их область применения ограничивается первым апреля )

Comment: @PashaPash не верю. Покажите наглядно) Тем не менее юзер 1 что-то напишет, а юзер 2 сотрет - как-то не камильфо)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну можете не верить, но реально ж удобная фишка :)